# How to center text inside :before pseudo element?

Tags: css, centering, pseudo-element

I have code like this:

```css
span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d8d9dd;
  border: 6px solid #262c40;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 40px;
  display: block;
}
span:before {
  content: attr(data-value);
  position: relative;
  white-space: pre;
  display: inline;
  top: -27px;
  left: -29px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span data-value="November 2016"></span>
<span data-value="May 2016"></span>
```

How can I center the text inside :before pseudo element to be in the middle of the span? Is it possible?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173675/12872199 for the most LOGICAL and correct answer (not hit and trail positioning)! ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best thing would be to *position* the `before` pseudo element *absolutely* with respect to the `span` using the popular centering technique:

```
top: 0;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -25px);
```

Note that -25px is to offset the text above the circles (which has height 25px) - see demo below:

```css
span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d8d9dd;
  border: 6px solid #262c40;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 40px;
  display: block;
  position:relative;
}
span:before {
  content: attr(data-value);
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre;
  display: inline;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -25px);
}
```

```html
<span data-value="November 2016"></span>
<span data-value="May 2016"></span>
```

[Source](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-center-a-text-inside-the-css-before-pseudo-element.html)

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before):

> [the `:before` pseudo-element] is inline by default

Giving inline elements a `width` does nothing, so you need to style it as `display: block` (or `inline-block` if that is more appropriate). It also turns out that you need to adjust the `left` value to approximately `-88px` to get the text centred over the circle.

```css
span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d8d9dd;
  border: 6px solid #262c40;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 40px;
  display: block;
}
span:before {
  content: attr(data-value);
  position: relative;
  white-space: pre;
  display: inline;
  top: -27px;
  left: -88px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span data-value="November 2016"></span>
<span data-value="May 2016"></span>
```

Comment: Though not explicitly mentioned, it should be noted that the `width` on the pseudo element is essential, as it alone gives it the space in which to be centred, otherwise it is just centred in its own length, effectively giving it the same alignment as the `li` item.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend against using negative translations. It might end up outside the viewport if you don't do it enough carefully.

Moreover, you shouldn't insert contents with pseudo-elements. Pseudo-elements should only be used for styling purposes. Like this:

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
span:after {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d8d9dd;
  border: 6px solid #262c40;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 10px auto 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span>November 2016</span>
<span>May 2016</span>
```

The text inside the span is centered due to `text-align: center`.

The pseudo-element circle is centered due to `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the jQuery UI slider by adding labels for handlers I don't think that it will work when you have text inside spans.

Answer (score 2):

We should use **LOGICAL CODE** and not any hit and trail and playing around with numbers!

I used flex in the pseudo element to center it first upon the span element.

Then i used transform to **Logically** position the pseudo element.

```css
/*styling to just make the presentation look good*/
body{
  border:5px solid black;
  padding:50px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

/* main stylings start here*/
span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d8d9dd;
  border: 6px solid #262c40;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 40px;
  display: block;
}
span:before {
  content: attr(data-value);
  width:150px;
  border:solid black 1px;
  
  /*use flex to center it to middle & upon the span*/
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  
  /*use transform and position it LOGICALLY (by considering border widths of the parent span and ofcourse using calc() )*/
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 2 * 6px), calc(-100% - 6px));
}
```

```html
<span data-value="November 2016"></span>
<span data-value="May 2016"></span>
```

I would request to use LOGICAL Code rather than design-breaking hit and trail values.
Write Responsive Code. Happy Coding!

Comment: Note that the question is from 2016 I don't think that there was a flex box back then. But is a very good answer. I'm adding a comment right now because someone upvoted my question and I've revisited the answers in 2022.

Comment: display flex rescued me for a similar issue of adding a fontawesome map pin to an address.  Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

I was beaten to this, but here is my solution:

```
span {
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: #d8d9dd;
   border: 6px solid #262c40;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   margin: 30px 0 0 40px;
   display: block;
}
span:before {
   content: attr(data-value);
   position: relative;
   white-space: pre;
   display: inline-block;
   top: -27px;
   left: -50px;
   width: 125px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

The changes are to use `inline-block` display on the `:before` style and to adjust the `left` and `width` of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block;` and add `margin-left:-87px`. where 87px derived from

100px(50% of whole width 200px)-13px(50% of span width 25px)

```css
span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d8d9dd;
  border: 6px solid #262c40;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 40px;
  display: block;
}
span:before {
  content: attr(data-value);
  position: relative;
  white-space: pre;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -27px;/*
  left: -29px;*/  
  margin-left: -87px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span data-value="November 2016"></span>
<span data-value="May 2016"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to center horizontally an html symbol inside pseudo's content element,so I used line-height property :

```css
details summary::after{
    content: "›";
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    color: #64C1E3 ;
    right: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid #64C1E3;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-family: emoji;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.anda {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(55, 26, 26);
        background-color: aqua;
        border-radius: 100%;
      }
      .anda::before {
        content:attr(data-text);
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background: rgb(55, 26, 26);
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
```

```html
<div class="anda" data-text="HTML5">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Doing this always works for me:

put some content in the element first
and the change in the z-index property of it in the CSS

Example:

Your HTML file

```html
<p>some content</p>
```

Your CSS file

```css
p{
  z-index:10;
}

p::after{
  content:'';
  /*rest of the code*/
}

/*use z-index as per your requirements*/
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question